# Is there an equivalent of Junit assetEquals with delta in Scalacheck

Tags: scala, junit, scalatest, scalacheck

I am porting some Junit tests(for Java code) into Scalacheck. One of the Junit tests is using

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double, double, double)

Now when I write Scalacheck property for the same is there a way to provide delta how Junit API offers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing doubles sucks :). Here is how ScalaTest helps you with it:

```
import org.scalatest._

class MyTest extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {

  ...

  100.0 should be (100.0 plusOrMinus 1e-9)

  ...
}
```

An alternative for `plusOrMinus` is `+-` method.

Comment: Worth noting: `plusOrMinus` is [deprecated](http://www.scalatest.org/release_notes/2.0) in ScalaTest 2.x in favor fo the `+-` operator, and [removed](http://www.scalatest.org/release_notes/3.0.0#expiredDeprecations) entirely in ScalaTest 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

ScalaTest works nicely with ScalaCheck, and the matcher I think you're looking for is at http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingNumbersAgainstARange